# Accessing a stored variable through a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am working on an inventory UI for my game and I've been stuck on this problem now for the past day, I'll do my best to explain the problem as clearly as I can.

I have a for loop that creates the rows for my inventory UI, it adds as many rows as there are items in the inventory. As there can be a different amount of unique items in the inventory at any given time it has to be flexible.

```
for (int i = 0; i < p1.getPi().getInventoryLength(); i++) {
            itemID = (p1.getPi().generateItem(p1.getPi().getItemID(i)).getItemID());
            ///////// ITEM ICON ///////////
            itemLabel = new JLabel(loadMenuIcon(p1.getPi().generateItem(p1.getPi().getItemID(i)).getIcon(), 20, 20));
            gc.weightx = 0.1;
            gc.weighty = (i+1 == p1.getPi().getInventoryLength()) ? 1 : 0;

            gc.gridx = 0;
            gc.gridy = i;

            gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
            gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
            inventoryPanel.add(itemLabel, gc);
            ///////// ITEM NAME ///////////
            name = new JTextField(p1.getPi().generateItem(p1.getPi().getItemID(i)).getItemName());
            name.setBorder(null);
            name.setEditable(false);
            name.setHighlighter(null);
            name.setFont(inGameFont.getFont());
            gc.weightx = 0.7;
            gc.weighty = 0;

            gc.gridx = 1;
            gc.gridy = i;

            gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
            gc.insets = new Insets(4, 0, 0, 0);
            inventoryPanel.add(name, gc);
            ///////// ITEM COUNT ///////////
            amount = new JTextField("x " + p1.getPi().getAmount(i));
            amount.setBorder(null);
            amount.setEditable(false);
            amount.setHighlighter(null);
            amount.setFont(inGameFont.getFont());
            gc.weightx = 0.1;
            gc.weighty = 0;

            gc.gridx = 2;
            gc.gridy = i;

            gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
            gc.insets = new Insets(4, 0, 0, 0);
            inventoryPanel.add(amount, gc);
            ///////// USE BUTTON ///////////
            useItem = new JButton("Use");
            useItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    InventoryClicks gc = new InventoryClicks(this, itemID);

                    if (inGameInventoryListener != null) {
                        inGameInventoryListener.formEventOccurred(gc);
                    }   

                }

            });
            useItem.setFont(inGameFont.getFont());
            useItem.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            useItem.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 18));
            useItem.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.LIGHT_GRAY));
            gc.weightx = 0.1;
            gc.weighty = 0;

            gc.gridx = 3;
            gc.gridy = i;

            gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
            gc.insets = new Insets(3, 0, 0, 0);
            inventoryPanel.add(useItem, gc);
```

The problem that I'm facing however is that the actionlistener that gets added to my buttons all end up with the same values in my itemID variable. 
This means that regardless of which button I press I always get the same end result.

```
        inventoryBag.SetInGameInventoryListener(new InGameInventoryListener() {

            @Override
            public void formEventOccurred(InventoryClicks c) {
                System.out.println(c.getID());
            }

        });
```

This is how I extract the information from the button that has been pressed.

I have tried a bunch of different methods for storing the itemID variable but I always end up at the same problem where I either cant access the correct variable or where I manage to save the variable but cant access it in my listener. 
I have tried storing the itemID variable in a hashmap together with the button hashcode

```
    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> buttonIndex;

    public HashMap<Integer, Integer> getButtonIndex() {
        return buttonIndex;
    }

buttonIndex.put(useItem.hashCode(), itemID);
```

```
buttonIndex = inventoryBag.getButtonIndex();

        inventoryBag.SetInGameInventoryListener(new InGameInventoryListener() {

            @Override
            public void formEventOccurred(InventoryClicks c) {
                System.out.println(buttonIndex.get(c.getID()));
            }

        });
```

I feel like the hashmap solution is on the right track if only I could get the correct key from just the source of inventoryClicks.

```
public class InventoryClicks extends EventObject {

    private int id;

    public int getID() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public InventoryClicks(Object source, int id) {
        super(source);
        this.id = id;

    }
```

I hope I managed to explain my problem somewhat decently, is the logic of my program completely off or is there a chance this could work ? I just picked out the bits of code that I thought would be relevant but if theres something missing I can upload more.

Comment: Could you clarify the type of "itemID"? Is it a primitive? Class? Primitive Wrapper(example: Integer, BigInteger etc...)?

Comment: @sigur itemID is an integer that holds the id for the respective item

Comment: I think the problem could be related to the ActionListener which operates with the itemID in its method; I am not sure, but some JVM "magic" could reuse the same instance. Try to create a class which implements the ActionListener but it recives the itemID as constructor parameter and store it in the object; then this ActionListener executes the operation with the itemID stored.

Comment: It looks like it's getting a different itemID each time. Perhaps you could either print the itemID variable or use a debugger to make sure that the itemID variable is set to a different id each time through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out!

```
useItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JButton item = (JButton) e.getSource();
                    InventoryClicks gc = new InventoryClicks(this, item.hashCode());
                    if (inGameInventoryListener != null) {
                        inGameInventoryListener.formEventOccurred(gc);
                    }   

                }

            });
```

I got the source of the correct button from e.getSource and copied it to a new button that I then extracted the hashCode from.

```
        inventoryBag.SetInGameInventoryListener(new InGameInventoryListener() {

            @Override
            public void formEventOccurred(InventoryClicks c) {

                System.out.println(buttonIndex.get(c.getID()));
            }

        });
```

I could then extract the hashcode in my inventoryListener and use it to find the correct ID from my hashmap(buttonIndex).